# storing a one-columns-file into a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, key

I have a file which looks like this:

```
    >Organism1
    ETTGDMND
    >Organism2
    PDELMESPEER
    >Organism3
    YERLLRRAQ
    >Organism1
    EDLTEVSGIGC
```

I want to create a dictionary in which the capital letters (=amino acid sequences) are the keys and the organism name is the value.
So far I have:

```
    dict1 = {}
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip() 
        if ">" not in line:        # '>' not in the line=amino acid seq 
            key = line             #assign the line into a variable 'key' 
            dict1[key] = []        #make this variable the keys of dict1
        else:                      #if '>'is in the line = organism
            value = line
            dict1[key] = value  
    print dict1
```

It raises the error message that 'key' is not defined. But I thought it is by saying key = line..?

A related question using the same input file.  If I wanted to call only on the amino acid sequence from that file (for another purpose), I did:

```
my_sequences = []
for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if ">" not in line:
        my_sequences = [line] # add these dna sequences to the list "my_sequences"
print my_sequences
```

but it only printed one sequence instead of all sequences.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Which came first, the key or the value?

Comment: Your first line is _>Organism1_. That means that the code will follow the `else` branch where `key` is not defined.

Comment: Ah that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Since your values always come before your keys, a straightforward approach is to "remember" the value in another variable that you can use when you get the key.  So, the following should work:

```
dict1 = {}
file = open("somedata.dat")
for line in file:  # note you can leave out readlines() here
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line[0] == ">":    # safer to check just first char
        value = line[1:]  # use [1:] to drop the ">" from the value
    else:
        dict1[line] = value
print dict1
```

If there are multiple lines of amino acid keys following a single value, the same value will be used for all keys.

For your second question, the problem is that this line:

```
my_sequences = [line]
```

always replaces `my_sequences`, regardless of its previous value, so you get a one-item list containing the last sequence processed.  Replace it with:

```
my_sequences.append(line)
```

which adds an item to the end of a list, and it'll do what you want.

Comment: Yeah great, that gives me what I need. Thanks!

Comment: another question apart from creating a dictionary-If I wanted to call only on the amino acid sequence from that file (for another purpose), I did                                                                                                                            my_sequences = []                                                                                   for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()        
    if ">" not in line:         
        my_sequences = [line]      #add these dna sequences to the list "my_sequences"
print my_sequences  #but that gives me only one sequence